# Can I use [[stage_in]] signature with [[buffer(0)]] signature in Metal(MSL)?

Tags: metal

Are the following MSL codes valid?

```
struct UniformBuffer
{
    float2 scale;
    float2 translate;
};

struct VertexInput
{
    float4 position [[ attribute(0) ]];
    float2 texcoord [[ attribute(1) ]];
    float4 color [[ attribute(2) ]];
};

struct VertexOutput
{
    //...
};

vertex VertexOutput main(constant UniformBuffer& ubo[[ buffer(0) ]], VertexInput input [[ stage_in ]])
{
    //...
}
```

If this code is valid, how should I specify the indices of the [[stage_in]] buffer and [[buffer(0)]] buffer when calling setVertexBuffer in Metal Application?

I tried to call the setVertexBuffer function based on the page at

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrendercommandencoder/1515829-setvertexbuffer?language=objc,

but I am not sure what value to specify for atIndex is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shader itself is valid. `stage_in` in the vertex shader implies that you are going to use `MTLVertexDescriptor` that you set on `MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor`. `MTLVertexDescriptor` contains `attributes` and `layouts`. Those are arrays of other descriptors. The buffer indices the `stage_in` variable "pulls" the data from are specified by setting the `bufferIndex` on `MTLVertexAttributeDescriptor`. The only thing you need is to make sure that you use indices that you aren't using for `buffer(i)` bind points.

Comment: Let me know if I can improve the answer conceptually. It can be sometimes hard to grasp the "input assembler" part of any graphics API.